# Numerically solve recurrence equation

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

I have the following recurrence equation

```
p[t_, s_] := 
 p[t, s] = ((1 + s)*p[t - 1, s]^2 + (1 + s)*
    p[t - 1, s]*(1 - p[t - 1, s]))/((1 + s)*p[t - 1, s]^2 + (1 + s)*2*
    p[t - 1, s]*(1 - p[t - 1, s]) + (1 - p[t - 1, s])^2)
p[0, s_] := 0.00001
```

and I would like to solve for when

```
p[50, s] == 0.8
```

One approach that worked for me was to first construct a list

```
listvals = Table[{s, p[50, s]}, {s, 0, 0.5, 0.0025}];
```

Then do a polynomial fit on these

```
fittedfunc[s_] = Fit[listvals, Table[s^k, {k, 0, 130, 1}], s];
```

and then solve for when

```
FindRoot[fittedfunc[s] == 0.8, {s, 0.4, 0.5}]
{s -> 0.414704}
```

I was just wondering though if there is perhaps some other, more direct way to do this, without having to approximate the curve first? I had a try with `?NumericQ` but couldn't quite get it work.
Anybody any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Interpolation` can also be used and I present this just this somewhat 'over the top' to illustrate a number of ways to check, hone in initial values etc.

I have 'simplified' the recursive function.

```
fun[s_, x_] := x/(2 x - x^2 + (1 - x)^2/(s + 1))
r[s_, n_] := Nest[FullSimplify[fun[s, #]] &, 0.00001, n]
tab = Table[{j, r[j, 50]}, {j, 0, 0.5, 0.001}];
if = Interpolation[tab];
ans = t /. First@NSolve[if[t] == 0.8, t];
p3d = ListPointPlot3D[
   Flatten[Table[{j, k, r[j, k]}, {j, 0, 0.5, 0.01}, {k, 0, 100, 1}], 
    1]];
Manipulate[
 Column[{DiscretePlot[r[s, x], {x, 0, 100}, Frame -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 1}, GridLines -> {{50}, {0.8}}],
   Plot[if[x], {x, 0, 0.5}, 
    Epilog -> {Point[{s, r[s, 50]}], 
      Text[Style["x", Red], {ans, r[ans, 50]}]}, 
    GridLines -> {{ans}, {0.8}}, Frame -> True],
   Show[p3d, 
    Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[{ans, 50, r[ans, 50]}]}], 
    ListPointPlot3D[Table[{j, 50, r[j, 50]}, {j, 0, 0.5, 0.01}], 
     PlotStyle -> Black],
    ListPointPlot3D[Table[{ans, j, r[ans, j]}, {j, 0, 100, 1}], 
     PlotStyle -> Black],
    Graphics3D[{Yellow, PointSize[0.04], Point[{s, 50, r[s, 50]}]}]
    ], Row[{"Answer:", ans}]
   }], {s, 0, 0.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this - that's also a very elegant approach!